# JavaScript random password generator with prompts for criteria

Tags: javascript

I am doing a homework assignment for a random password generator that prompts the user for length and character type. I am stuck on syntax for inputting more than one character type at a time, and when a password is generated, it is only outputting index 0 of whatever character string i specified. (Seeing "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" was only funny the first time.)

```js
// Get references to the #generate element
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  //Length
  var length = Number(prompt("Enter the length of your password between 8-128 characters."))
  //character types
  var charType = prompt("What should we include in your password? Type 'uppercase, lowercase, numbers, symbols' to include. ")

  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  function password() {
    var charGen = {
      lowercase: 'abcdefghijklmnop',
      uppercase: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP',
      numbers: '0123456789',
      symbols: '!@#$%^&*()-_=+',
    };
    var charSet = charGen[charType.toLowerCase()];
    var retVal = "";
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      retVal += charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charGen.length));
    }
    return retVal;
  }

  passwordText.value = password();
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

function copyPassword() {
  document.getElementById("password").select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  alert("Password copied to clipboard!" + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<br>
<input id="password">
```

I initially tried if/else statements for strings of characters, but no output was given, due to syntax errors. switched to "var charGen" assigning properties to charGen. Output now given, but only one character type can be specified in the prompt and output is the 0 index of the specified string (length is working fine now)

Error I'm receiving is "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "charAt")" and I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Not that it probably matters much for a homework assignment, but please do note that `Math.random` is not cryptographic strength randomness and should not be used for password generation IRL.

Comment: The error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "charAt")` means that the javascript engine tried to find a property named `charAt` on some variable but that variable is undefined. So when you see this error, look to the left of the property mentioned in the error. In your case that would be the variable `charSet` which tells you one very important thing - the variable `charSet` is `undefined`. So basically you're code is saying `undefined.charAt(...)`

Answer (score 0):

`charGen` is your lookup, it doesn't have a `length`. You want the length of your `charSet`, which is your string of characters.

```js
//               Should be `charSet`, not `charGen` ----+
//                                                      |
//                                                      v
retVal += charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length));
```

With the full answer here:

```js
// Get references to the #generate element
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  //Length
  var length = Number(prompt("Enter the length of your password between 8-128 characters."))
  //character types
  var charType = prompt("What should we include in your password? Type 'uppercase, lowercase, numbers, symbols' to include. ")

  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  function password() {
    var charGen = {
      lowercase: 'abcdefghijklmnop',
      uppercase: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP',
      numbers: '0123456789',
      symbols: '!@#$%^&*()-_=+',
    };
    var charSet = charGen[charType.toLowerCase()];
    var retVal = "";
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      retVal += charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length));
    }
    return retVal;
  }

  passwordText.value = password();
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

function copyPassword() {
  document.getElementById("password").select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  alert("Password copied to clipboard!" + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<br>
<input id="password">
```

Comment: `TypeError: charSet is undefined`

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, I've got a much better understanding, I didn't think length was the issue but I had completely missed that step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the user's input for the charTypes `var charTypes = charType.toLowerCase().split(', ');`, and then use those charTypes to generate the charSet:

```
charSet = "";
for(var i=0; i < charTypes.length; i++) {
  charSet += charGen[charTypes[i]];
}
```

Lastly, the character needs to use `retVal += charSet.charAt(... charSet.length));` (the length of the set of characters) instead of `retVal += charSet.charAt(... charGen.length));` (the length of the charType array).

```js
// Get references to the #generate element
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  let passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
  
  //Length
  let length = Number(prompt("Enter the length of your password between 8-128 characters."))
  //character types
  let charType = prompt("What should we include in your password? Type 'uppercase, lowercase, numbers, symbols' to include. ")
  
  passwordText.value = password(length, charType);

  function password(length, charType) {
    let charGen = {
      lowercase: 'abcdefghijklmnop',
      uppercase: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP',
      numbers: '0123456789',
      symbols: '!@#$%^&*()-_=+',
    };
    
    var charTypes = charType.toLowerCase().split(', ');
    charSet = "";
    for(var i=0; i < charTypes.length; i++) {
      charSet += charGen[charTypes[i]];
    }
    
    console.log(charSet);

    var retVal = "";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      retVal += charSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length));
    }
    return retVal;
  }
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

function copyPassword() {
  document.getElementById("password").select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  alert("Password copied to clipboard!" + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<input type="text" id="password" />
```

Comment: Oh! This makes sense, I wasn't setting a length. I really appreciate the help with parsing, thank you!